# boot camp create windows 7 option can't be marked?

Tags: windows-7, mac, multi-boot, macbook, boot-camp

i have a macbook 7,1( mid,2010)based on the tutorial from apple i started boot camp but the create windows 7 option was hidden so i replaced it with boot camp 4(it was 5 before).now the option to create bootable usb is visible but can't be marked.

after a a little search i found out that this option seems to be hidden for the macs with optical drives.

now my question is how can i install windows 7( supported by the mac 7,1 based on apple's tutorial ?

should i use DVD ? if so, how ?

my os is OS X yosemite

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your optical drive is working, the best choice is a DVD. I would recommend a RW DVD. It takes longer to burn but is reusable. It is not sufficient to just burn the iso file to the DVD. You must burn the image stored in the iso file to the DVD.